# Displaying data in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am new to salesforce. How to write response data from Page Controller in visualsource page. That I want to populate all the text field data whose values are retrieved from controller contating database and and the retrieved data iswritten to the response. How to write data into response in controller. So 2 questions...

1. How to write response data from Page Controller in visualsource page
2. How to write data into response in controller. So 2 questions

Comment: this looks like a good new years resolution to go through the Trailhead modules that teach SFDC development - specifically Visualforce

Comment: This doesn't describe my problem

Comment: I need something like request.getAttribute in Viseualforce pag

Comment: You can access any public variable in Visualforce using this notation {!variableName}. You can read this post , as it explains VF in very detail from basics - https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Visualforce

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code for you.

```
        <apex:pageBlock title="Edit Account">
            <apex:pageMessages/>
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:inputField value="{! Account.Name }"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{! Account.Phone }"/>        
                <apex:inputField value="{! Account.Industry }"/>        
                <apex:inputField value="{! Account.AnnualRevenue }"/>
           </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:commandButton action="{! save }" value="Save" />        
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Contacts">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Account.contacts}" var="contact">
            <apex:column>
                <apex:outputLink
                    value="{! URLFOR($Action.Contact.Edit, contact.Id) }">
                    Edit
                </apex:outputLink>
                &nbsp;
                <apex:outputLink
                    value="{! URLFOR($Action.Contact.Delete, contact.Id) }">
                    Del
                </apex:outputLink>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column value="{!contact.Name}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!contact.Title}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!contact.Phone}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>


        </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

For custom controller you can check @Ratan's answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

Apex class

```
public class customCtrl{

    public List<Contact> getAllContacts(){
       return [SELECT FirstName, LastName, Email FROM Contact];
    }
}
```

VF page

```
<apex:page Controller="customCtrl">
    <apex:form>     
        <apex:pageBlock title="Contacts">
          <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!AllContacts}" var="contact">
            <apex:column value="{!contact.FirstName}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!contact.LastName}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!contact.Email}"/>
          </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

This page will display all the contacts

**[Trailhead: A New Approach to Learning Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/visualforce_fundamentals)**